# Google Cloud Speech-to-text doesn't return isFinal=true response depending on which microphone I use

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am writing a nodejs program using Google Cloud Speech-to-text. The audio recorded by the sox recorder of node-record-lpcm16 is delivered to the streamingRecognize function. At the end of recording one sentence, a message with isFinal as true should be returned, but the problem is that depending on the microphone, sometimes (when using Macbook Pro internal mic) it is returned and sometimes (when using Airpods Pro) it is not.

**Plus**, this issue occurs when I use ko-KR for recognizing. It works well in en-US as a recognition language.

```js
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

module.exports.getGoogleCloudSpeech = (speechProviderOptions) =>  {
  return {
    startListening(dispatch) {
      const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
      console.log('[speech] Invoked');
      const request = {
        config: {
          encoding: 'LINEAR16',
          sampleRateHertz: 16000,
          languageCode: 'ko-KR',
        },
        interimResults: true,
      };
      let stopTimeout;
      let stopped = false;
      let expireTime;

      // Create a recognize stream
      const recognizeStream = client
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on('error', () => {
          dispatch({ type: 'error' });
        })
        .on('data', data => {
          if (data.results[0]) {
            console.log(data);
            const result = data.results[0].alternatives[0];
            if (data.results[0].alternatives[0]) {
              dispatch({
                type: 'result', 
                result: {
                  transcript: result.transcript,
                  isFinal: data.results[0].isFinal,
                },
              });
            }
          }
        });

      // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
      let totalSize = 0
      let recording = record
        .record({
          sampleRate: 16000,
          threshold: 0,
          recordProgram: 'sox',
        });

      recording.stream()
        .on('data', buf => {
          totalSize += buf.length;
          if (!expireTime) {
            console.log('[speech] Ready to listen');
            expireTime = Date.now() + 59000;
            dispatch({ type: 'ready', expiryTime: expireTime });
            stopTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
              if (!stopped) {
                recording.stop();
                console.log('[speech] Stop (timeout)');
                stopped = true;
              }
            }, expireTime - Date.now());
          };
        })
        .on('error', console.error)
        .pipe(
          recognizeStream,
          { end: true },
        )
        .on('end', () => {
          const time = totalSize / 16000 / 2;
          console.log(
            '[speech] API end, total size',
            totalSize,
            time.toFixed(2) + 's'
          );
          dispatch({ type: 'end' });
        });
      return {
        stop() {
          clearTimeout(stopTimeout);
          if (!stopped) {
            recording.stop();
            console.log('[speech] Stop (user)');
            stopped = true;
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue has to be investigated further, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.